# VBA Excel if Cell Is Not Equal to formula then

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I want to check if a cell is this formula then execute a part 2 script

The code Simplified

```
Range("B1:C1").Select
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" And ActiveCell <> "=formula1" Then Sheet1Macro
```

the complete code (long)

```
Range("B1:C1").Select
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" And ActiveCell <> "=IF(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH(""DKB"",RC[-2]),0),IFERROR(SEARCH(""Cox"",RC[-2]),0),IFERROR(SEARCH(""2020"",RC[-2]),0)),RC[-1],"""")" Then Sheet1Macro
```

I'm just asking on how to check if the cell is a formula because I insert rows and that changes the formula from A2:F99 to A99:F189 for example

Comment: Add .formula to activecell. Debug.print current formula to make sure you need "=" sign

Comment: actually `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` in your case

Comment: Also, `ActiveCell.HasFormula` returns True or False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" And Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH(""DKB"",RC[-2]),0),IFERROR(SEARCH(""Cox"",RC[-2]),0),IFERROR(SEARCH(""2020"",RC[-2]),0)),RC[-1],"""")" Then Sheet1Macro
```